# Android connected to Car system

Tags: obd

How can connect my android app to car system for example to get "Level fuel" information or any others info!

Comment: Can you please tell us more about your car? Does it support digital interfacing? Have you seen similar integration of car with another platform like iOS?

Comment: Do you mean something like [OBD2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics) apps, e.g., [Torque](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.prowl.torquefree)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All modern cars have CPU which measures and controls few parameters of its engine.  These CPU(s) will have an interface socket (looks like SCART connector) with which issues are diagnosed at service center.  There is a special hardware which goes into this socket and can transmit engine parameters through Bluetooth.  Google Play Store has an app called [Torque](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.prowl.torque&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5wcm93bC50b3JxdWUiXQ..) which when installed in an Android phone, can receive such parameters and displays on the screen.

I am not too sure whether the OBD device can detect fuel level, but it does sense a lot of other engine related parameters like HP torque etc.

Comment: Its possible that the car gives fuel info over HTTP GET, then Tasker might be useful. It's just one example.

Comment: According to a review on the app in Play Store, fuel info is displayed.

Comment: I make other search about OBD implemntation in Java , and I find an open source project OBD-II Manager ,[link]http://obd.codeplex.com/......but I stil to test it with app android .

Answer (score 0):

You would like to try [Fuelio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kajda.fuelio) which advertise to give fuel and other info that cost money. I haven't tested it, however.